# How to create an event on Facebook?

Tags: objective-c, ios, facebook

I'm trying to create an event, but all tutorials that I read are outdated or don't work anymore.

```
[FBRequest
 startWithGraphPath:@"me/events"
 parameters:params
 HTTPMethod:@"POST"
 completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection,
                   id result,
                     NSError *error) {
     if (error) {
         NSLog(@"Error: %@", result);
     } else {
         NSLog(@"Success: %@", result);
     }
 }];
```

The completion handler is called, but with an HTTP error #403. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

If the completion handler returns with HTTP/403 Forbidden, there’s something wrong with your authentication. Your Facebook session is probably not valid, or not open at all. Please take a look at the [Facebook iOS SDK Tutorial](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/login-with-facebook-using-ios-sdk/) to learn how to establish a valid session. In essence you should do something like this:

```
static NSString *PublishStreamPermission = @"publish_stream";
[FBSession
    openActiveSessionWithPublishPermissions:@[PublishStreamPermission]
    defaultAudience:FBSessionDefaultAudienceEveryone allowLoginUI:YES
    completionHandler:^(FBSession *session, FBSessionState status, NSError *error) {
        if ([session state] != FBSessionStateOpen) {
            // failed to open a valid session
        } else if ([[session permissions] containsObject:PublishStreamPermission]) {
            // session opened, permissions granted, now you can post
        } else {
            // session opened, but requested permissions not granted
        }
}];
```

Comment: in the function create event works now XD . the problem was a @"create_event" permission .